# "Relay access denied" when sending email via php mail in zpanel

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I have installed zpanel on my centos server i am using php mail function to send signup email to my clients. it was working fine on my virtualmin server but when i moved my site to zpanel server it is showing "relay access denied."

Here is the server logs. please help me in this.

```
smtp 16 16:11:37 localhost sendmail[16531]: s8GCBbfZ016531: from=apache, size=422, class=0,

nrcpts=1, msgid=<f97ee7e25d449fc85c6f0ec66f239995@seo1pagerank.com>, relay=apache@localhost

Sep 16 16:11:37 localhost postfix/smtpd[16532]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Sep 16 16:11:37 localhost postfix/smtpd[16532]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from
localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]: 454 4.7.1 <user@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=
<apache@localhost.localdomain> to=<user@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<localhost.localdomain>
Sep 16 16:11:37 localhost sendmail[16531]: s8GCBbfZ016531: to=user@gmail.com, ctladdr=apache 
(48/48), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30422, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], 
dsn=4.7.1, stat=Deferred: 454 4.7.1 <user@gmail.com>: Relay access denied

Sep 16 16:11:37 localhost postfix/smtpd[16532]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
```

Why this denying my email kindly update i have tried all things at my level.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 3):

Use a valid sending address from your domain.  `localhost.localdomain` is NOT a valid Internet domain.  Consider using a `noreply` address, for which you track bounced email.  If you want users to be able to reply use a `Reply-to:` header with the address to which replies should be sent.

Answer (score 1):

Find invalid domain:

```
echo $(hostname).$(awk -F' = ' '/^mydomain/{print$2}' /etc/postfix/main.cf)
```

Once edited, run the commands:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
service postfix reload
```

Comment: issue has been resolved kindly close.